# Can you embed a Unity3d mobile project into an existing native mobile app?

Tags: android, iphone, unity, ios

I am creating an application for both Android and iPhone that will have a few mini games in it. I would like to create the non game section in native Android and iPhone. My question is, is it possible to have a native app that will incorporate the Unity mini game I am creating all inside one apk and ios project?

Comment: This looks like a very specific case. Have you tried asking on Unity/Xamarin community forums?

Comment: We're looking to do the same...did you find an answer?

Answer (score 4):

That's been asked a ton of times at http://answers.unity3d.com

Where there is a demand there is usually a supply

The Native Toolkit plugin from prime31
http://prime31.com/unity/docs/#nativeToolkitDoc

An excerpt from their product description:

> The NativeToolkit Plugin is your bridge for communicating between Unity and iOS. It is designed to make displaying view controllers as simple as possible. A single call to activateUIWithController will load the specified view controller and it will search for iPad specific nib files to load as well. This allows you to easily create menus, pause screens, inventory screens or any other UI your game needs via drag and drop in Interface Builder.